# Clear disk space to in the boot folder?

Tags: disk

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  When I attempt to install updates. I receive a message that says, "The volume boot has only 0 bytes disk space remaining".  How do I clear disk space in the boot folder?  This has not occurred since I installed 14.04 LTS last year.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have a separate boot partition. At a command promot, type

df -h

What is listed ?